# Hide wordpress wp-admin url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, hide, admin

I am not sure, what I have to do to make the WP-ADMIN URL to change to a custom one. I have tried lots of plugin and nothing seems to work I even tried the htaccess method it did not work as well.
I have tried WPS hide admin plugin which seems to work for lot of people but that as well has not worked till now for me i am not sure what I have to do to make it work. Does any body know anything to hide the admin URL?

Comment: Are you trying to change your admin URL into something else?

Comment: yes, i want to change my admin url to something else for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There is a WordPress Plugin that may help you. Follow the tutorial from given link.

https://managewp.com/change-your-wordpress-login-url

Comment: Bro, i have tried this plugin, no luck :(, this plugin has been upgraded to latest version with that, i was able to hide wp-admin or login page, but the custom url does not work anymore no matter what i do, it just throws 404 error even though the custom url is correct

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try below plugin?

### Lockdown WP Admin

This plugin will hide WordPress Admin (`/wp-admin/`) when a user isn't logged in. If a user isn't logged in and they attempt to access WP Admin directly, they will be unable to and it will return a 404. It can also rename the login URL.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Plain url to Post Name in Permalink setting and use WPS HIDE plugin.. its works for me